# Change the width of an element using angular $animator

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-animation

I have a container that changes its width via Javascript. So, I'd like to animate it, using $animator.

How could I do something like:

```
var width = 200;
$animator.start(function(element) {
    element.css({width: width});
});
$animator.animate();
```

?

Notice that I doesn't have an css style to change it. I did it with another containers, but in this case is necessary to use js.